# what does lock_guard always owns the lock mode of the referenced mutex mean?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, c++98

I was reading [this](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/mutexes/locking.html) article on mutexes. and it states

> The biggest difference between lock_guard and unique_lock is that
>   lock_guard always owns the lock mode of the referenced mutex and
>   unique_lock doesn't. Indeed, unique_lock may not even reference a
>   mutex.

so far I only understand is that when we need to construct a lock but not lock the mutex we could use the `std::unique_lock`. It is an improved version of `std::lock_guard`Apart from that I do not see much difference. I would appreciate if someone could explain what does owning lock mode of a referenced mutex mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `std::unique_lock` you can specify option in constructor.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock

There is three options `std::defer_lock_t`, `std::try_lock_t` and `std::adopt_lock_t`.
`std::defer_lock_t` Does not lock the associated mutex.

`std::try_lock_t` Tries to lock the associated mutex without blocking by calling `m.try_lock()`. The behavior is undefined if the current thread already owns the mutex except when the mutex is recursive.

`std::adopt_lock_t` Assumes the calling thread already owns m.

When no option is specified (i.e. constructor called only with mutex param) - mutex is simply locked with `mutex.lock()` function.

When you use `std::lock_guard` you can only specify one option (`std::adopt_lock_t`), in other case mutex will be locked with `lock` function.

In all this cases in destructor of `lock_guard`/`unique_lock` mutex will be unlocked with call to `mutex.unlock()` function, if `mutex` is locked.